# How to fix caching issue in PHP data from database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, cache

Im trying to use the code belong for my plugin development but there is a caching issue (I think). Please below for the details.

**Problem**

I created filter to accept the customized url, and I'm querying the database but it seams like the result value is not changing in the browser but changing in the database. So basically the data passed is not returning the updated value from the database.

**Code**

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('coupon/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?coupon=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'coupon';
    return $query_vars;
});

add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == false || get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }

    ob_clean();
    ob_start();

    // Check if coupon exists
    global $wpdb;
    $coupon = get_query_var('coupon');

    $coupon_query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_urls WHERE coupon = %s AND claimed_at IS NULL', $coupon);
    $coupon_available = $wpdb->query($coupon_query) ? true : false;

    if(!$coupon_available) {
        header('Location: /'); // Redirect to landing page
        exit();
    }
    
    return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/client/index.php';;
} );
```

**index.php (Update function with the form)**

After clicking submit button, the code below will run.

```
$update_query = "UPDATE wp_urls SET 
                        `email` = %s, 
                        `phone_number` = %s, 
                        `first_name` = %s, 
                        `last_name` = %s, 
                        `message` = %s, 
                        `claimed_at` = %s 
                        WHERE `coupon` = %s";

//  Execute query
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($update_query, $placeholder_values));
```

**Expected Result**

The expected result should redirect the user to the `header('Location: /');` if the coupon is not available.

Any idea?

Comment: "value is not changing in the browser but changing in the database. Your code doesn't write anything to the database. What is changing in the database?

Comment: You're activating the output buffer, but where do you use the content of it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Please check again, Ive updated my question. Also, please check the query.

Comment: @moped Just tried it there but not actually fixing the bug.

Comment: What submit button? That update code has nothing to do with anything in the redirect code, so I don't see how they're related? What do you think is cached?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Basically, when you visit `/coupon/CODE123` url, it will return a from, so when you submit the form, it will run the update query. They are related since you cannot access the url `/coupon/CODE123` if you dont use the `add_rewrite_rule`. I think the browser is caching the page or the url; Im not 100% sure, but based on my code above, if the sql condition does not met, the user must be redirected in the home page. But the problem is, it is not redirecting even if the query condition does not met. But when I check the database table, it is updating. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jonjie It seems to me that you're doing the update after the select query - you should do it the other way round - update the db columns if the form was submitted, then do the select query (and redirect action).

Comment: @SallyCJ Yup, that's exactly what Im doing. But when I visit the url again, the query should not met the condition so it means, it should redirect to the home page.

Comment: Ah sorry (if you've seen my previous comment that I've deleted), I didn't really notice the `claimed_at` in your SQL queries. So have you already tried doing the update first? That should fix the issue, if your form submits to itself (i.e. same page).

Comment: @SallyCJ The code is actually working, BUT when I visit the url with the same coupon code again, it stays which should not because the coupon code is already claimed, so the user must be redirected to the home page. Please check my query again for the query details

Comment: @Jonjie, so you mean you submitted the form and then manually visited the same coupon URL later on? Are you sure the query `SELECT * FROM wp_urls WHERE coupon = %s AND claimed_at IS NULL` actually returned a row? (well after the `%s` is replaced) Also, try using `wp_redirect()` instead of `header()`. And have you actually tried clearing your (browser and site) caches? And/or try loading the coupon page on a different browser (window)?

Comment: @SallyCJ yup I tried it all. Also regarding clearing the browser cache, it is a client side so the user should not be doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119798/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-jonjie).